# How to join 2 independent tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm using SQL there are 2 independent tables 
.1 table one provides the codes and id's the data looks like

```
Code    ID
AUD     WH1
CND     WH1
```

.2 tables has the long description for these codes which looks like

```
colval            Description

AUD|WH1         Australia records
CND|WH1         Canada records
```

the column 'colval' is concatenation of columns 'code' and 'id' with delimiter '|' of #table 1. how to join these tables to get the result like

```
Code      Description
AUD      Australia records
CND      Canada records
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `join` with concatenation logic:

```
select t1.*, t2.description
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.colv = t1.code || '|' || t1.id;
```

In SQL Server:

```
select t1.*, t2.description
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.colv = concat(t1.code, '|', t1.id);
```

Unfortunately, Oracle supports `CONCAT()` but with only two arguments.  So for code that works on both databases:

```
select t1.*, t2.description
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.colv = concat(concat(t1.code, '|'), t1.id);
```

Comment: This worked for me in oracle but for SQL server its failed with  Incorrect syntax near '|'. I tried with single | pipeline also then getting  the error as "The data types nvarchar and varchar are incompatible in the '|' operator."

Comment: for sql server,  use concatenate function,  instead of ||

Comment: on t2.colv =concat(t1.code,'|',t1.id) this worked for me in SQL server

Comment: Any idea  how this query is modified to work for both SQL as well Oracle ?

Comment: There is no common cancatenate function to sql server and oracle both for 3 params.  If you realy want the same syntax,  you can create stored function in these 2 databases with the same name,  lets say "sf_concat".  Inside the function the code do the concatenate in the right way according to each db.  The query will use this function and will be identical in both.